Starfield node canvas - responsive handling
I want to improve this code base to control the number of nodes, connectivity, charge, speed, colors, adapt the canvas/density to provide consistency on responsive handling - are there similar canvas examples that maybe contain more stability?

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/awesome-darkness-kw48ps?file=%2Fsrc%2FStarField.js
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react'

const StarField = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  const stars = []
  const FPS = 60
  const numStars = 100
  const mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight

    // Push stars to array
    for (let i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
      stars.push({
        x: Math.random() * canvas.width,
        y: Math.random() * canvas.height,
        radius: Math.random() * 1 + 1,
        vx: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) - 25,
        vy: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) - 25,
      })
    }

    const draw = () => {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter'

      stars.forEach((s) => {
        // ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.fillStyle = '#061c5b'
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(s.x, s.y, s.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.stroke()
      })

      ctx.beginPath()
      stars.forEach((starI) => {
        ctx.moveTo(starI.x, starI.y)
        if (distance(mouse, starI) < 150) ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y)

        stars.forEach((starII) => {
          if (distance(starI, starII) < 150) {
            ctx.lineTo(starII.x, starII.y)
          }
        })
      })

      ctx.lineWidth = 0.05
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#061c5b'
      ctx.stroke()
    }

    const update = () => {
      stars.forEach((s) => {
        s.x += s.vx / FPS
        s.y += s.vy / FPS

        if (s.x < 0 || s.x > canvas.width) s.vx = -s.vx
        if (s.y < 0 || s.y > canvas.height) s.vy = -s.vy
      })
    }

    const tick = () => {
      draw()
      update()
      requestAnimationFrame(tick)
    }

    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
      mouse.x = e.clientX
      mouse.y = e.clientY
    }

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)

    tick()

    return () => {
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
    }
  }, [stars, mouse])

  const distance = (point1, point2) => {
    const xs = Math.pow(point2.x - point1.x, 2)
    const ys = Math.pow(point2.y - point1.y, 2)
    return Math.sqrt(xs + ys)
  }

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
}

export default StarField

